# Perform batch execution without using BLOB

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Can I perform batch execution against Azure ML web service without using BLOB?

I'm reading the data from SQL database into a CSV file stream. Can I stream this directly to the service without actually saving in and reading back the result from the BLOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BES doesn't work with streams. The data needs to be stored somewhere for AML to access the data. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-consume-web-services#batch-execution-service-bes for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Import Data/Export Data module in your graph, you don't need web service input/output, and hence blob is not involved.

Comment: Can you explain this more? Which graph are you referring to?